# label text updated through javascript but not reflected on webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I was working on a page with multiple drop down controls, on each dropdown selected index changes event i wanted to show some message in the modal popup, and thus i showed the modal popup with a label on that and dynamically changed label value from code behind JS function call, value get changed but not reflected on the web page. here is the code snippet:

C# code:

```
     public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {            
        //builds page controls
        this._BuildControls();

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // get the target of the post-back, will be the name of the control
            // that issued the post-back
            string eTarget = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();

            //source database server dropdown changes event called
            if (eTarget.Contains("SourceDatabaseServer"))
            {
                this._DisplayMessage = "Loading source database...";

            }
            else if (eTarget.Contains("SourceDatabaseName"))
            {
                this._DisplayMessage = "Loading source host name...";
            }
            else if (eTarget.Contains("DestinationDatabaseServer"))
            {
                this._DisplayMessage = "Loading destination database...";
            }
            else if (eTarget.Contains("DestinationDatabaseServer"))
            {
                this._DisplayMessage = "Loading destination host name...";
            }
            else
            {
                this._DisplayMessage = "Cloning portal...";
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "updateMessage('" + this._DisplayMessage + "');", true);
        }

    }
```

Javascript file function:

```
function updateMessage(message){
 var text = document.getElementById('LoadAndSaveClonePortalDataModalModalPopup'); 
 text.innerHTML=message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a label in your modal form.

```
function updateMessage(message) {
  var $modal = $('#LoadAndSaveClonePortalDataModalModalPopup'),
      $messagelbl = $modal.find('#lblMessage');
      $messagelbl.val(message);
      $modal.modal("show");
}
```

Read the section explaining how to vary modal content [Varying modal content based on trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) if you need more clarification